# Is there any shortcut in VS Code for navigating to HTML of angular component or vice versa?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut available for VS Code for navigating from angular `component.ts` file to its `component.html` file or
`component.html` file to `component.ts` file?

or is there any extension available for it?

It very difficult to open component's HTML file or vice versa while working in ZEN mode or full screen mode.

I know we can use ctrl + shift + p to open command palate and we can open desired file, but I'm looking for any keyboard shortcut if available.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't one at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This extension is what you are looking for:
[angular2-switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher)

To take your example, to switch from component.ts to the corresponding component.html, use shortcut:

```
alt+o
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, VS code gives you simple shortcut to navigate in opened files by

```
ctrl + tab
```

this will open the next file opened, and if you want to navigate to the previous file again in case of multiple files open, just use

```
ctrl + shift + tab
```

Comment: I'm not looking to switch between already open pages, looking for way to open HTML or component file in angular from currently opened Component or HTML file, like visual studio.